# Windows server distribution list or Exchange shared mailing list?

Tags: windows, exchange, mailing-list, distribution-lists

Do you think it is better a distribution list in active directory or a shared mailing list of exchange for company internal mail alias (one address to many recipients)? I can not unserstand pro and con.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to decipher but I think I understand.  It is better to create a distribution list within Active Directory thus allowing all your users to easily send mail using the DL.  If you create this in exchange itself your users must then share this address with others so they may add it their own outlook.